# How to write a multi-line value in a Cucumber Test data table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

For cucumber testing using data table, usually is like this:

```
|name| job title |
|Lee | doctor    |
|Tom | teacher   |
```

How can I deal with the situation that the content for job title is very long, and it is impossible to stay in one line?

Comment: OK.  I'm curious.  How long is the job title?

Comment: very long, may not be job title, something like job description

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

There is my idea. You can try this:

***Gherkin***

```
When man is <name>
Then he is <job title>
|name| job title         |
|Lee | doctor            |
|Tom | super_long_string |
```

***Step definition***

```
Then /^he is$/ do |job_title|
  if job_title == super_long_string:
   job_title = "long_string"
end
```

!Not tested